# How to update SELinux version in CentOS? (Docker install)

Tags: docker, centos, yum, selinux

I'm trying to install docker-engine-1.13.1 on my CentOS machine following this instruction: https://docs.docker.com/cs-engine/1.13/#install-on-centos-7172--rhel-70717273-yum-based-systems

But I keep getting this error message

[image]

So the problem is that my SELinux version is low (3.13.1-23), and I need higher version (3.13.1-60)

I've tried 'yum -y update selinux-policy-targeted' but didn't work.
Can anyone help me update selinux?
Or is there any other way I can install docker properly?

Comment: What do you mean the update command didn't work ? Show the error messages if any. I see CentOS repo has higher version available: http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/

Comment: The yum update command returned this message: "Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile No packages marked for update"

Comment: delete yum cache and try again. `yum --enablerepo=* clean all; yum update`